# asp.net mvc 5 how to display data in table header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tableheader

i am developing a scheduler in asp.net mvc 5.

i am new to it,

**my question is**, how i can display data on table header from my sql server database

here is my data base
[image]

i want when user 6a loging, it display the **"Blue Surgery"** and **"Grey surgery"** in table header

when user 22b login, it display the **"Surgery One"** & **"surgery Two"** in the table header

here is my table
[image]

here is my View code

```
 <tr>
                    <th style="width:50px;"></th>

                    <th id="header1">Surgery 1</th>

                    <th id="header2">Surgery 2</th>

                    <th id="header3"></th>

                    <th id="header4"></th>

                    <th id="header5"></th>

                    <th id="header6"></th>

                </tr>
```

here is my controller code

```
  // GET: Schedules/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var schedule = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser;

        //ViewBag.ClinicName = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "FirstName");

        var doctor = db.Doctors.ToList().Where(d => d.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(doctor, "DoctorID", "DoctorName");

        var surgery = db.Surgeries.ToList().Where(d => d.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.SurgeryID = new SelectList(surgery, "SurgeryID", "SurgeryName");


        var patient = db.Patients.ToList().Where(p => p.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.PatientID = new SelectList(patient, "PatientID", "PatientName");

        return View();
    }
```

my Index in Controller

```
// GET: Schedules
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //var schedules = db.Schedules.Include(s => s.AspNetUser).Include(s => s.Doctor).Include(s => s.Surgery).Include(s => s.Patient);
        //return View(schedules.ToList());
        var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var schedule = db.Schedules.Where(x => x.ClinicName == currentUser);


        return View(schedule);

        var surgery = db.Surgeries.Where(x => x.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.Headers = surgery.Select(s => s.SurgeryName).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: why pplz are making negative marking, i am stuck in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work

*Controller*

```
ViewBag.Headers = schedule.Select(s => s.SurgeryName).ToList();
```

*Html*

```
<tr>
    <th style="width:50px;"></th>
    @if (ViewBag.Headers != null && ViewBag.Headers.Count > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Headers.Count; i++){
            <th id="header_@i">@ViewBag.Headers[i]</th>
        }
    }
</tr>
```

*This will fix your empty column Problem, but you should really work with Viewmodels*

```
 <tr>
     <th style="width:50px;"></th>
     @if (ViewBag.Headers != null && ViewBag.Headers.Count > 0){
         for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
             <th id="header_@i">@(ViewBag.Headers.Count > i ? ViewBag.Headers[i] : "")</th>
         }
     }
 </tr>
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>.Count' cannot be used like a method.



Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>.Count' cannot be used like a method.

Source Error: 


Line 75: 
Line 76:                         <th style="width:50px;"></th>
Line 77:                         @if (ViewBag.Headers != null && ViewBag.Headers.Count() > 0)
Line 78:                         {
Line 79:                             for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Headers.Count(); i++)

Comment: with this, it display the data from schedule table in the database, i want to display the data from Surgeries table in the database, because "schedule " does not contains the SurgeryName, it contains the "SurgeryID"

Comment: Then replace schedule.Select with surgery.Select (Or the model you want to use)

Comment: facing a little problem, if we have 2 records, it displays 2 records, how i can fix the limit of columns to 6, remaining 4 columns should be empty......like the picture i share

Comment: can you explain regarding viewmodel? please

Comment: [A very good explanation of Viewmodel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).